# Download snap "lxd" (10756) from channel "stable" (invalid credentials) when trying to install

Tags: upgrade, snap

Just upgraded from bionic to cosmic. Part of that process migrates from deb lxd to snap lxd. The upgraded succeeded except for the lxd package. I get this error when trying to complete the upgrade or when installing lxd snap using snap command.

```
snap install lxd
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Download snap "lxd" (10756) from channel "stable" (invalid credentials)
```

Why do I get this? What credentials? Where is the snapd error log?

Update as requested in attempted answers:

`grep snap /var/log/syslog` :

```
May 30 00:21:14 delays snapd[30230]: storehelpers.go:441: cannot refresh snap "core": snap has no updates available
May 30 00:21:14 delays snapd[30230]: autorefresh.go:389: auto-refresh: all snaps are up-to-date
May 30 10:21:14 delays snapd[30230]: storehelpers.go:441: cannot refresh snap "core": snap has no updates available
May 30 10:21:14 delays snapd[30230]: autorefresh.go:389: auto-refresh: all snaps are up-to-date
May 30 15:11:14 delays snapd[30230]: storehelpers.go:441: cannot refresh snap "core": snap has no updates available
May 30 15:11:14 delays snapd[30230]: autorefresh.go:389: auto-refresh: all snaps are up-to-date
May 30 15:37:32 delays snapd[30230]: api.go:1079: Installing snap "lxd" revision unset
```

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you submit the content of `/var/log/syslog` once you run `sudo snap install lxd`?

To do so, open a terminal and type:

```
$ grep snap /var/log/syslog
```

### Solution #1

Usually, when this error occurs, you can resolve it by removing your credentials from `~/.snap/auth.json` and by trying to re-authenticate.

**Edit:**

### Solution #2

First, try to stop `snapd`

```
$ sudo systemctl stop snapd.service
```

Take a back-up and remove the `/var/lib/snapd/state.json`

```
$ sudo mv /var/lib/snapd/state.json /var/lib/snapd/state.json.bck
```

Start again `snapd`

```
$ sudo systemctl start snapd.service
```

Login to Snap

```
$ snap login
```

Update all Snap packages

```
$ snap refresh
```

Remove broken Snap

```
$ snap remove lxd
```

Try to install lxd again

```
$ snap install lxd
```

Comment: Thank you, #1 worked great. I wonder if I should file a bug against snap for this. It seems like if auth fails it should do this for me.

Comment: @Jay_silly_evarlast_Wren I'm glad that you managed to resolve your issue. (You can mark it as the 'Accepted' answer). There's already a bug related to this on launchpad since 2016 ... https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1611068

Answer (score 1):

You could try installing lxd with the sudo prefix as shown below:

`sudo snap install lxd`

Comment: No, I get the exact same error if run with sudo.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution accidentally:

1- log out of snap:

```
#snap logout
```

2- Go to `Settings --> Online Accounts` and delete all accounts you have.

3- Now simply:

```
#snap refresh
```